# AWS Certificate Manager, cannot get https for subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, aws-certificate-manager

I have a hosted zone with my main domain. I already added a Load Balancer and configured it to route to my web app. This already works with https and http. So far so good.

Now I wanted to add a subdomain something like: domain.com (routes to my frontend) api.domain.com (routes to my backend).
The routing is already working but I cant use https. I tried to get a ssl certificate exactly for this domain (api.domain.com) but this got stuck in pending.

I also tried to use a wildcard (*.domain.com). With this I can connection to my service like this: https://api.domain.com, but the webbrowser says the connection is not safe.

Route 53 entries:
[image]

Certificate manager
[image]

Shouldn't be the wildcard (*.domain.com) working for my api. Subdomain?
And do you know why the first two certificates are stuck in pending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certificates are stuck in pending if they're waiting to be approved. The conditions (DNS records or email verification) have not yet been met.

If the domain is unsafe then the SSL for the domain has either expired, is not from a valid CA or is not included as a valid domain on the generated certificate.

Comment: The last two certificates stayed in pending for about 30 minutes, the other two now about 10 hours. 
But should be the wildcard be working for my subdomain?

Comment: The wildcard should be working for your subdomain as long as its one level deep. You're probably worth having one SSL that contains the root and the wildcard domain on it

Comment: The two urls looks like this:
https://papasmuenzen.com/
https://api.papasmuenzen.com/

But the second one is considered not safe

Comment: So should I create a new certificate for 
papasmuenzen.com and *.papasmuenzen.com

Comment: Looks fine to me: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=api.papasmuenzen.com&latest. And yes you should simplify the SSL by having both on the same certificate :)

Comment: So maybe its just when I try to call the api vie browser?^^
I will simplify and configure it again ^^
And i will use your posted website for testing :D

Comment: Your SSL passes checks on https://api.papasmuenzen.com/, The only concern is that it has a few issues with cipher suites and also its running TLS 1.0 which it should not be. Take a look at these too :)

Comment: ok thats kind of good I will have a look at that!
Thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217129/discussion-between-chris-williams-and-christoph).